# Send Promise for every chunk of fetched rows from nodeJS to Client

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures, promise, stream

I am using stream.pause() and stream.resume() to fetch 10k rows from mssql and send them and then resume back the fetch process. For sending the 10k rows, I am resolving the promise. But only first batch of 10k rows are sent. Further rows are not sent because it is resolved once. How to use promise to send rows every time stream is paused? Can someone help me on this? Here is my code.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
            request.stream = true;
            console.log('query>>>>>>>>>>>')
            request.query(SPQuery);
            let rowsToProcess = [];
            request.on('row', row => {
                rowsToProcess.push(row);
                if (rowsToProcess.length === 10000) {

                    resolve(rowsToProcess)
                  request.pause();
                  processRows();
                }
              });
              request.on('done', () => {
                  processRows();
              });

              function processRows() {
                // process rows
                rowsToProcess = [];
                request.resume();
              } });
```

Comment: once a Promise is resolved, it stays that way forever -- it becomes an immutable value at that point -- and can then be observed as many times as necessary.

Comment: Correct. In my case every time batch of rows data is changing and I am trying to resolve promise for each batch of rows. Is there anything I need to change on client side? On client side I am fetching data just once.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to move the 'resolve' into the 'request done' method after the last 'processRows' and use a callback for the progress reports for each batch of rows. The calling code can then wait on the promise until everything is done and the callback function is called in-between. I.e.

```
queryAllRows = (onProgressCallback) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        request.stream = true;
        console.log('query>>>>>>>>>>>')
        request.query(SPQuery);
        let rowsToProcess = [];
        request.on('row', row => {
            rowsToProcess.push(row);
            if (rowsToProcess.length === 10000) {

              request.pause();
              onProgressCallback(rowsToProcess); // <---- callback here
              processRows();
            }
          });
          request.on('done', () => {
              processRows();
              resolve(); // <---- resolve here
          });

          function processRows() {
            // process rows
            rowsToProcess = [];
            request.resume();
          } });
}
```

Comment: J.R. Thank You for suggesting the answer. I tried this option but after callback the flow does not even go to processRows(). Looks like it loops around for long time.

Comment: Currently I am fetching data only once at client side. Here is the code:
async function getData(api){
    let data = await (await (fetch(apiurl)
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw Error(res.statusText);
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
                return false;
            })
    ))
    return data;
}

Comment: I'm not sure how the 'queryAllData' function is called here. Does the browser log reveal anything? Maybe add some console logs to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: I already printed console.logs both server and client side. It enters inside queryAllData and after onProgressCallback is called. It takes almost 5 minutes to again start from the queryAllData and then on browser it shows server 500 error. Nothing else is printed. 
queryAllData is called once when route is hit.

Comment: Sorry not 500 error but ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on browser console.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the whole picture and don't know what is happening in onProgressCallback; maybe just remove the callback to see if it actually progresses through to the 'done' bit; maybe this is no longer a problem with the Promise.

Comment: If you see the logic in above code. I am fetching 10000 rows in rowsToProcess array, pausing the database stream, and then resolving the promise. after that I am emptying the rowsToProcess array and Resuming the Stream to fetch next set of rows. So in done only the last set of rows will be sent and only last set of rows may be resolved. I already did that.

Comment: Hi, I have a question here for onProgressCallback. From where it is sent and what functionality does it have?

Comment: The idea was that OnProgressCallback runs the functionality that you previously had for 'resolve' (but as a callback function instead) to deal with each 10000 row batch. The code that awaits the promise returned by queryAllRows would continue once all batches are done.

Comment: Okay, what you call OnProgressCallback is this function for me where I am calling for one route, this getData function to get rows:


 router.get('/api/loadDashboardTransactionQueueData', async (req, res, next) => {
        try{
             let resultSet = await getData();
            res.send(resultSet);

        }catch (e){
            logger.error(e);
            next(e);
        }
    });

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// .   My logic is inside getData function in another file.

Comment: It is getting a bit complicated to follow the logic and figure out where things stop working. If the callback does not return then things can't continue but I don't know why. Sorry that I was not able to help you.